# How to use chalk to drill harder material

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, materials

How can we use chalk to make a hole (small hole, less than 10 cm in diameter) in harder material, in a reasonable timeframe (hours or days, not years). The lower the technical level, the better.

The chalk is writing chalk:

[image]

Target include wood, brick wall, rock, iron and steel.

I consider [abrasive blasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abrasive_blasting) acceptable, but it seems overkill.

Comment: This is a standard physics/materials question, there are no world-building elements here.

Comment: Is such a big picture necessary to illustrate your point or could you make  it a bit smaller?  (That's more of a personal preference for leaving space for the important problem description instead of unnecessray visual distractions.)

Comment: How is this question outside the scope "How to achieve a specified effect". Normally, we don't drill with brittle material such as chalk.

Comment: I think it would be back on-topic if we had some worldbuilding context for the problem. Allowing for solutions the author may not have thought about.

Answer (score 9):

Had you but chalk enough, and time<sup>1</sup>, sure. The other material being "harder" only means that it takes a lot more chalk to drill through the harder material that would take the harder material to drill through chalk.

Of course, if the other material is hard enough, drilling could take *years* - or more. Abrasive blasting is exactly the same thing, except faster.

If you brush a steel plate with a chalk, you'll notice - after a little while - a slight dulling of its sheen, because the chalk succeeded in removing a few tenths of a micron of steel from the plate. Do that one hundred million times and you've gouged a foot-deep trench in the plate (and destroyed a million chalk sticks).

---

(1) https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44688/to-his-coy-mistress